# firebase gets value and alerts it even if the condition is false

Tags: javascript, firebase

This code logs in the user, and if its logged in, it would get the data from the real time database and alert the window. But for some odd reason it alerts the window even tough the user isn't logged in.

```js
function login(){
  var email = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    window.alert("Sign in failed! Wrong Password or Email")
    // ...
  });
}

database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('test');
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

function gotData(data){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      window.alert(data.val()); // the value is 9810 in the database
    } else {
      
    }
  });
}

function errData(err){
  console.log('Error!');
  console.log(err);
}
```

you can see the alert here. I can assure you that it automatically runs if the site loads.

[image: the alert]

anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: can you log the user before the alert

Comment: when logging the user, it gives this mess and more. this was all i could fit in the screenshot https://imgur.com/gvr63PT @AkashDathan

Comment: you want to alert only if the user is verified ?

Comment: no, i want the alert when the user logs in

Answer (score 0):

Use `if (user.emailVerified) {..}` to check if the user is verified.